# Refactoring out common method arguments in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, dry

I have a mailer with methods that look like this:

```
def review_comment_notification comment_id, locale = I18n.locale
    comment = Spree::Comment.find(comment_id)
    assign(:review, review_data(comment.commentable))
    assign(:user, user_data(comment.commentable.user))
    assign(:commenter, user_data(comment.user))
    assign(:unsubscribe, unsubscribe_data(self.action))
    assign(:comment, comment_data(comment))
    mail(
      email_id: REVIEW_COMMENT_NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATE,
      recipient_address: comment.commentable.user.email,
      version_name: localized_version(locale)
    )
  end

  def store_credit_receipt(user_id, store_credit_id, locale = I18n.locale)
    store_credit = Spree::StoreCredit.find(store_credit_id)
    user = Spree::User.find(user_id)
    assign(:user, user_data(user))
    assign(:store_credit, store_credit_data(store_credit))
    assign(:unsubscribe, unsubscribe_data(self.action))
    mail(
      email_id: STORE_CREDIT_RECEIPT_TEMPLATE,
      recipient_address: user.email,
      version_name: localized_version(locale)
    )
  end

  def reset_password_instructions user, store_id, locale = I18n.locale
    # Dual handling here kept due to external libraries.
    user = user.respond_to?(:id) ? user : Spree::User.find(user)
    set_store(Spree::Store.find(store_id)) if store_id
    password_reset_url = spree.edit_password_url(
      reset_password_token: user.reset_password_token
    )
    assign(:password_reset_url, password_reset_url)
    mail(
      email_id: RESET_PASSWORD_INSTRUCTIONS_TEMPLATE,
      recipient_address: user.email,
      version_name: localized_version(locale)
    )
  end

  def welcome user_id, store_id, locale = I18n.locale
    user = Spree::User.find(user_id)
    set_store(Spree::Store.find(store_id)) if store_id
    assign(:user, user_data(user))
    mail(
      email_id: WELCOME_TEMPLATE,
      recipient_address: user.email,
      version_name: localized_version(locale)
    )
  end
```

Now we need the current locale at runtime to make decisions on what version of the email to send. Also note this is not a standard ActionMailer mailer.

The problem is, to accomplish this, I have to add locale = I18n.locale to EVERY method across ALL of our mailers.

This is a major smell for me. But because I need the locale at the time of method invocation, I cannot make this a class default (unless I'm missing something)

Is there a way to refactor this added logic out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are instance methods, right?  Do what one does when an object needs data everywhere, pass it in during construction:

```
mailer = WhateverMailer.new(locale: I18n.locale)
mailer.welcome(user_id, store_id)
```

So you just store the locale as an instance variable in your mailer.  Looking at the rest of the methods, it seems like that pattern could help clean up other things like `user_id`.